# Can tf.linalg.svd be used within a custom loss function in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would really like my loss function to have some terms related to the singular values of my output. Can `tf.linalg.svd` be used? I have built the loss function I want, but it immediately goes off the rails and makes the weights all `NaN`.  I suspect the gradients are not being computed properly.  The loss function works during evaluation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `tf.linalg.svd` can be used in loss functions, the raw_ops `Svd` has a gradient, as can be seen on the [`tf.raw_ops` documentation page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops#Svd):

> | Op Name | Has Gradient |
> | --- | --- |
> | Svd | ✔️ |

You can check yourself with a tiny example :

```
>>> tf.random.set_seed(0)
>>> a = tf.random.uniform((3,3))
>>> a
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.29197514, 0.20656645, 0.53539073],
       [0.5612575 , 0.4166745 , 0.80782795],
       [0.4932251 , 0.99812925, 0.69673514]], dtype=float32)>
>>> with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(a)
        b = tf.linalg.svd(a)
>>> tape.gradient(b,a)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.43832093,  0.48833036,  0.41132155],
       [ 2.3028214 , -0.7062633 ,  1.9096204 ],
       [ 0.80203193, -0.41204354, -0.6789427 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: I pulled the gradients and got all NaNs in my case.  But I'm still at version 2.0.0 Tensorflow.  What version is this from?

Comment: EDIT:  I see the tf.raw_ops for 2.0.0 indicates svd has gradients.  I can also reproduce your result.  Something about svd within the context of my loss function must be the problem.